# Google Maps API v3 adding multiple markers w/ info windows w/ custom text

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, marker, infowindow

I am making a website over cyclists killed in Norway. For my project I have been using google maps api v3, but I have vague familiarity with javascript. You can see my result so far here: http://salamatstudios.com/googlemapstest/

Basicly I want to have multiple markers with infowindows on each one. Each one of the infowindows will contain:
Name (age),
Location,
Date of death,
Read more (which will be linked to a page on the website itself).

Like this example here: http://salamatstudios.com/bicycles/

I tried working with just one marker and infowindow and that worked just fine. When I want to add new markers with custom info windows on each I get stuck. At the moment I have 3 markers on different locations as seen in the first link, but none of the info windows appear when I click the marker..

How do I go around it to code it so the infowindows appear? And how can I have custom text in every infowindow? I am going to have about 30-40 markers on the map when it is done. All of the info windows will have different types of information.

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(65.18303, 20.47852),
      zoom: 5,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,


      // MAP CONTROLS (START)
      mapTypeControl: true,

      panControl: true,
      panControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
      },

      zoomControl: true,
      zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
      },

      streetViewControl: true,
      streetViewControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
      },
      // MAP CONTROLS (END)



    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
        mapOptions);


    // -------------- MARKER 1
    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(59.96384, 11.04120),
    map: map,
    icon: 'img/bike5.png'
    });


    // MARKER 1'S INFO WINDOW
    var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Name<br />Location<br />Date<br /><br /><a href="http://www.db.no" target="_blank">Read more(test link)</a>'
    });
    // End of infowindow code

    // Adding a click event to the marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
    // Calling the open method of the infoWindow
    infowindow1.open(map, marker);
    });
    // -------- END OF 1st MARKER


    // -------------- MARKER 2
    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60.63040, 8.56102),
    map: map,
    icon: 'img/bike5.png'
    });

    // MARKER 2'S INFO WINDOW
    var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Name<br />Location<br />Date<br /><br /><a href="http://www.db.no" target="_blank">Read more(test link)</a>'
    });
    // End of infowindow code

    // Adding a click event to the marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
    // Calling the open method of the infoWindow
    infowindow2.open(map, marker);
    });
    // -------- END OF 2nd MARKER


    // -------------- MARKER 3
    var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60.39126, 5.32205),
    map: map,
    icon: 'img/bike5.png'
    });

    // MARKER 3'S INFO WINDOW
    var infowindow3 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Name<br />Location<br />Date<br /><br /><a href="http://www.db.no" target="_blank">Read more(test link)</a>'
    });
    // End of infowindow code

    // Adding a click event to the marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'click', function() {
    // Calling the open method of the infoWindow
    infowindow3.open(map, marker);
    });
    // -------- END OF 3rd MARKER


  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Would be great if some could give me a clue. I've tried searching around a bit, but I can't really find my answer. Thanks in advance! :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to attach the infowindow to the correct markers.  Currently they are all associated with "marker", which doesn't exist (and should cause an error message in the javascript console when you click on the markers).

Inside the click listener change:

```
infowindow1.open(map, marker);

infowindow2.open(map, marker);

infowindow3.open(map, marker);
```

To:

```
infowindow1.open(map, marker1);

infowindow2.open(map, marker2);

infowindow3.open(map, marker3);
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_multipleInfoWindows.html)

Comment: Wow! That worked instantly. Thank you very much. Also is there any way of having a function that closes the last infoWindow when you click the next marker and open a new infoWindow?

Comment: You mean like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map1.html) (translated to v3 from the example in [Mike Williams' v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic1.htm)) (I think of this as "v2 infowindow behavior")? If you only want one infowindow open at a time, share the same infowindow for all the markers.  If this answered your question, please [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Thanks again! I tested it out for a while and failed a lot, but I got it to work as I wanted in the end. Thanks for your time, geocodezip :-)

Comment: For anyone else who has the same the same problem in the future they can look at this: http://salamatstudios.com/bicycles2/

Answer (score 2):

In addition to HoangHieu Answer when you use for loop it better to use it this way:

```
marker.info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: 'some text'
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  this.info.open(map, this);
});
```

Comment: this is actually a smarter approach instead of instantiating `infowindow1`,  `infowindow2`,  etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
    // Calling the open method of the infoWindow
    infowindow1.open(map, marker);
    });
```

change to

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
    // Calling the open method of the infoWindow
    infowindow1.open(map, this);
 });
```