# google maps api 3 with 2 markers

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

i am using the bellow code from google api v3 to show the map.
the question is because i am no good in javascript,how is possible to show up a second marker in the map? (one marker is my location and second marker to be my store?)
here is the code from html i use.thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.215642,-2.615666);
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 12,
          center: myLatlng,
          scaleControl: true,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatlng,
              map: map,
              title:"mytitle"
      });
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API v3 adding multiple markers w/ info windows w/ custom text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825290/google-maps-api-v3-adding-multiple-markers-w-info-windows-w-custom-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fixed..
here is the code changed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.078833, 23.737843);
     var storelng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.079576, 23.736706);
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 18,
          center: myLatlng,
          scaleControl: true,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatlng, map: map,title:"mytitle"


      });


          var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: storelng,map: map,title:"mytitle"
});

      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```