# Adding multiple locations to google js map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to add 3 locations to a Google map I have embedded in a website I am working on. Right now the map is working as intended with the single location pin. Is there a way to modify the js file to add the additional points?

```
// ==========  START GOOGLE MAP ========== //
function initialize() {
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(30.227686, -81.386146); 



var mapOptions = {
zoom: 14,
center: myLatLng,
disableDefaultUI: true,
scrollwheel: false,
navigationControl: false,
mapTypeControl: false,
scaleControl: false,
draggable: true,
mapTypeControlOptions: {
mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'roadatlas']
}
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),  mapOptions);



var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  icon: 'img/location-icon.png',
  title: '',
 });

 var contentString = '<div style="max-width: 300px" id="content">'+
  '<div id="bodyContent">'+
  '<h5 class="color-primary"><strong>Location 1</br> Ponte Vedra   Office</strong></h5>' +
  '<p style="font-size: 12px">103 B Solana Road </br>' +
  'Ponte Vedra, FL 32082</br>' +
  'Phone: 904-273-2717</p>'+
  '</div>'+
  '</div>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: contentString
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
infowindow.open(map,marker);
});

var styledMapOptions = {
name: 'US Road Atlas'
};

var usRoadMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
  roadAtlasStyles, styledMapOptions);

map.mapTypes.set('roadatlas', usRoadMapType);
map.setMapTypeId('roadatlas');
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);






// ========== END GOOGLE MAP ========== //
```

I am trying to include these 3 latitude/longitude sets on my map:
(30.227686, -81.386146)
(30.650060, -81.455185)
(30.056330, -81.535824)

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API v3 adding multiple markers w/ info windows w/ custom text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825290/google-maps-api-v3-adding-multiple-markers-w-info-windows-w-custom-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code with the original and two additional markers (only an infowindow on the first).

code snippet:

```js
// ==========  START GOOGLE MAP ========== //
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'));

  // I am trying to include these 3 latitude/longitude sets on my map: (30.227686, -81.386146) (30.650060, -81.455185) (30.056330, -81.535824)

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(30.227686, -81.386146),
    map: map,
    // icon: 'img/location-icon.png',
    title: '1',
  });
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(30.650060, -81.455185),
    map: map,
    // icon: 'img/location-icon.png',
    title: '2',
  });
  var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(30.056330, -81.535824),
    map: map,
    // icon: 'img/location-icon.png',
    title: '3',
  });
  
  // show all the markers on the map, replaces the mandatory zoom/center parameters in mapOptions
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
  bounds.extend(marker2.getPosition());
  bounds.extend(marker3.getPosition());
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  var contentString = '<div style="max-width: 300px" id="content">' +
    '<div id="bodyContent">' +
    '<h5 class="color-primary"><strong>Location 1</br> Ponte Vedra   Office</strong></h5>' +
    '<p style="font-size: 12px">103 B Solana Road </br>' +
    'Ponte Vedra, FL 32082</br>' +
    'Phone: 904-273-2717</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  var styledMapOptions = {
    name: 'US Road Atlas'
  };

  var usRoadMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
    roadAtlasStyles, styledMapOptions);

  map.mapTypes.set('roadatlas', usRoadMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('roadatlas');
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
// ========== END GOOGLE MAP ========== / /
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the other 2 markers (similarly to how you implemented the `marker` object above, but make sure to assign different values to `position`).